# Pyttsx not producing a sound

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyttsx

I'm trying to use pyttsx for text to speech on windows 7 but it does not produce any speech.

```
Import pyttsx
Engine=pyttsx.init('sapi5')
Engine.say('hello')
```

This is my code no error and exceptions are coming but there is no text to speech conversion

Answer (score 1):

Python is a case sensitive language, and must be installed on your machine for you to use this library. If/when Python is set up on your Windows 7 machine, try this code:

```
import pyttsx
engine=pyttsx.init() # The init function doesn't take any parameters 
engine.say("hello") #I prefer double quotes, but single quotes work too
```

There's a list of examples here: https://pyttsx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html#examples

Answer (score 1):

You also have to add this to the final line.

```
Engine.runAndWait()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try these:

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()
engine.say('hello')
engine.runAndWait()
```